# find a value in excel across multiple worksheets and workbooks using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro that finds the value "a" and replaces with value "b" across multiple worksheets and workbooks
the macro loops through files in folder and files in subfolders and replaces all the values it can find.

now i want the macro to return the file name in column E of the worksheet the macro is written in, ONLY IF changes where made in the file ( so if a was replaced with b return file name in colum E)

but my current code it only returns the file name of the first workbook it runs through.

my codes starts at sub search and it takes as an input sub()

```
Sub FindReplaceAcrossMultipleExcelWorkbooksFreeMacro(Path As String)

    Dim CurrentWorkbookName As String
    Dim ExcelCounter As Integer
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Object
    Dim FindReplaceCounter As Integer
    Dim FindandReplaceWorkbookName As String
    Dim FindandReplaceWorksheetName As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim Shape As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim look As String

    FindandReplaceWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    FindandReplaceWorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
  
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Path)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files              'Loop through every File in Active Workbook's folder path
    
        If InStr(1, oFile.Type, "Microsoft Excel") <> 0 And InStr(1, oFile.Name, FindandReplaceWorkbookName) = 0 And InStr(1, oFile.Name, "~") = 0 Then 'If the File Type contains the phrase Microsoft Excel isn't the current Excel Workbook and is NOT Lock File
            Set ExcelWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & oFile.Name) 'Open Excel Workbook
            CurrentWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Name of Active Excel Workbook that was opened
            Application.Workbooks(CurrentWorkbookName).Activate 'Ensure open Excel Workbook is active for future reference using ActiveWorkbook
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'Limit screen flashing when Excel Workbooks opened and when Find & Replace is completed
            FindReplaceCounter = 2
            LastRow = Workbooks(FindandReplaceWorkbookName).Sheets(FindandReplaceWorksheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Identify Last Row in Column A
            Do Until FindReplaceCounter > LastRow 'Complete the Find and Replace for all values in Column A & B
                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Loop through every Excel Worksheet in Active Excel Workbook

                    Set myrange = ws.UsedRange.Find(what:="ben")
                    If Not myrange Is Nothing Then
                    
                        Workbooks(FindandReplaceWorkbookName).Sheets(FindandReplaceWorksheetName).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ExcelWorkbook.Name
                        
                    End If
    
                    ws.Cells.Replace what:=Workbooks(FindandReplaceWorkbookName).Sheets(FindandReplaceWorksheetName).Cells(FindReplaceCounter, 1).Value, Replacement:=Workbooks(FindandReplaceWorkbookName).Sheets(FindandReplaceWorksheetName).Cells(FindReplaceCounter, 2).Value
                
                Next ws
                
                FindReplaceCounter = FindReplaceCounter + 1
                
            Loop
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Save                  'Save Active Excel Workbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Close                 'Close Active Excel Workbook

        End If
        
    Next oFile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True            'Turn Excel ScreenUpdating back on

    Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
  
    Exit Sub
  
End Sub


Sub Search()

    FindReplaceAcrossMultipleExcelWorkbooksFreeMacro (Cells(2, 3).Value)

    MsgBox "The Find and Replace has been completed."
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, maybe the code below can help you to compare it with your case.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim wb As Workbook
Dim oFSO: Dim oFolder: Dim oFile
Dim fn As String: Dim sh As Worksheet: Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
.Range("E:E").ClearContents
End With

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("D:\test")
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
fn = oFile.Name
If InStr(fn, "test") Then GoTo nextfile:
    Workbooks.Open oFile
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each sh In .Worksheets
            For Each cell In rg
                If Not sh.Cells.Find(cell.Value) Is Nothing Then
                    sh.UsedRange.Replace what:=cell.Value, Replacement:=cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
                wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
                    fn & " - " & sh.Name & " : value " & cell.Value & " is replaced with " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
            Next
        Next
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
nextfile:
Next oFile
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To test the code, create 3 workbooks :

1. Name the first wb "test.xlsm", this is the wb where the code resides.
    In test.xlsm sheet Sheet1, make two column header in column A and B, and name it : FIND in A1 and REPLACE in B1. Under FIND, put data such as aaa in A2, bbb in A3, ccc in A4. Under REPLACE, put data such as XXX in B2, YYY in B3, ZZZ in B4.
2. Create other two workbooks, name it as you like. In each wb, put aaa and/or bbb and/or ccc to whatever cell whatever sheet as many as you like.
3. put test.xlsm and the other two workbooks in one folder in drive D:, name the folder "test".
4. Run the code in test.xlsm. Make sure that the other two workbooks is close.

There are three loops in the code.
The first is to loop to each file in test folder
The second is to loop to each sheet of that file
The third is to loop to each FIND/REPLACE value in sheet Sheet1 test.xlsm

On the first loop, it open the file / workbook (which is not test.xlsm) 
then it loop to each sheet of that opened wb
on looped sheet, it loop to each data under FIND/REPLACE in sheet1 test.xlsm, and check if the looped cell value is found in the looped sheet, then it perform two process : (A) the found value is replaced with replace value (B) write the information in column E sheet1 of test.xlsm

Please note, the code doesn't write information on the looped sheet of the looped workbook which is being opened. It's just replace to a new value if the value to be replaced is found.

If you run the sub for the second time, there shouldn't be any information in column E sheet Sheet1 in test.xlsm.